# Is there an elegant way to copy data to an almost-structurally-identical type?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Suppose I have defined the following two types, the first one for initially receiving JSON and the second one to represent the same records but with possibly-null values having received defaults:

```
public class JsonInputAsReceived {
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string employeeNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? effectiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class JsonInputWithDefaults {
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string employeeNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime effectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is one implementation for a method to apply those defaults:

```
public static JsonInputWithDefaults setDefaults1(JsonInputAsReceived original) {
    return new JsonInputWithDefaults {
        company = original.company,
        employeeNumber = original.employeeNumber,
        effectiveDate = original.effectiveDate ?? DateTime.Today
    };
}
```

This works fine. But if my model types have a lot of properties, with nested collections, etc, then this gets noisy adding any "useful" code.

**Is there any elegant way to define two almost-the-same types so that I can copy the "same" part without having to code it manually?**

I can't come up with anything that doesn't either (a) sacrifice type-safety (reflection, Dictionary<,>) or (b) involve manually implementing the almost-copy operation.

Comment: Take a look at AutoMapper

Comment: Plus plus to AutoMapper.  It's not any more elegant internally, but you don't need to deal with the mess

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid writing your second Data Structure if you do not care about the original. For example, rewriting the effectiveDate property in original class (JsonInputAsReceived ) as as

```
private DateTime? _effectiveDate;
public DateTime? effectiveDate 
{
       get
       {
        if(!this._effectiveDate.HasValue)
            this._effectiveDate = DateTime.Today;
        return this._effectiveDate;
       }

       set { this._effectiveDate = value; }
}
```

You could now deserialize your object as

```
string json = @"{company:'abc',employeeNumber:'23'}";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonInputAsReceived>(json);
```

This would also ensure you do not have to recreate the entire data

Comment: Ah. That's actually pretty elegant! :-)